# Difference between array name and pointer to the first element in c

Tags: c

As I have learnt,array name acts like a pointer to first element.But:

```
int c[]={0,1,2};
printf("%d \t %d",c,&c[0]); //Different values,Why?
```

Also then why `*c=0`?

Comment: `*c` is the same as `c[0]` and you have set the first element of `c` to be `0` so that explains that part.

Comment: You should print pointers with `%p`, not `%d`. Sometimes it doesn't matter much, on some platforms it does a lot.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. `&c[0]` is an `int*`, but `%d` expects an `int`. You should cast the pointer to `void*` and use `%p`, or (assuming your platform supports this) cast to `uintptr_t` and use one of the macros from `<inttypes.h>`.

Answer (score 11):

Just a guess: you're on a platform with 64-bit pointers and 32-bit `int`. Your code passes two pointer values to `printf`, which then interprets these as `int` values; that might print the two halves of a 64-bit pointer as two separate integers.

You should print pointers with `%p`, not `%d`, after casting them to `void*`.