# the address of the array and the address of its first element is a backfill question

Tags: c

I wondered and still have not found an answer to it.
Its essence is as follows: the address "a" and address a [0]match, But at the same time at the same address are 2 different values.
The name of the array is a pointer to its first element, therefore, in its value has the address "a [0]" and everything is logical here, but when I look at the address "a [0]" it coincides with the address "a". At the same time, the meanings "a" and "a [0]" are different!

Why?!

[image]

Comment: Never post images of code or output. [Edit] your question to include it as text, and use the editor tools to format it as code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between array name and pointer to the first element in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465143/difference-between-array-name-and-pointer-to-the-first-element-in-c).

Comment: Aside: the proper syntax is `printf("%p\n", (void*)&a);`

Comment: Hallo! Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem, as text *in the question itself*. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Note that  _"why? why? why?"_ will lead to _"Bye Bye Bye"_ ..:-)

Comment: The meaning of `a` and `&a[0]` are the same in the context of using them as a function argument.

Comment: Imagine you have 3 kids and have the eldest point to the 1st seat of the 1st carriage of a train; the middle kid point to the 1st carriage of the train; and the youngest point to the train. Now say you are 1Km away... **do the kids all point to the same place?** What if you asked then to point to the next thing (next seat, next carriage, next train) possibly a few times?

Comment: @pmg I think I do understand C type system, but your kids example beats me :) To me it borders on relativity theory and Schrödinger principle )))

Comment: Lol @SergeyA. I think it may need some work in the English writing department, maybe with some illustrative code added in. Thanks, I guess ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can't even count how many C/C++ learners were burnt by this **wrong** assumption (apparently still taught in schools) that a name of C/C++ built-in array is a pointer to the first element.

This assumption leads to deep misunderstanding and distrust of built-in type system, and it is simply wrong. It is true that in some usage scenarios (a lot of them, actually) the name of array is converted (decayed it is said) to the address of the first element. But it is a conversion.

The truth is, the first element of the array resides in a certain address. If you get an address of this first element, you will end up with a pointer to the first element type. If you get an address of the array itself, you will get a pointer to the array, it is a different pointer type.

The fact that those two pointers might have the same byte representation (i.e. point to the same physical memory) is irrelevant and moot. The sooner you understand and accept it, the fewer "why why why" experiences you will live through.